# Scrollable textview text turns black

Tags: android

I am currently developing an electronic guide for Latvian traveler. I have a scrollable 'textview' which is going to show information about object which is selected. So the problem is when i touch the text and start to scroll it is looking like this [good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkJY2.png)
but when i touch it a little longer it turns black and after i scroll it for three lines text color is white again.[bad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnS9h.png)

So the question is how to make it stay white on longpress or where the problem could be?

My textviews code:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:scrollbars = "vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/rect"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Comment: is @drawable/rect is .xml file?, just try to remove background or transparent it and test working or not.

Comment: @vajapravin tryed it and still the same result :(

Comment: try to set text selectable false android:textIsSelectable="false"

Comment: @vajapravin then it doesn't compile and the error  is **Description Resource Path Location Type
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'textIsSelectable' in package 'android'**

Comment: @vajapravin still nothing. Could that error be related to API i'm developing for? if yes i'm developing for Android 2.2(API 8) and up.

Comment: are you trying this on an emulator??

Comment: @Archie.bpgc No. i'm testing it on HTC wildfire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just came across this issue, so maybe someone will make use of this answer:
Define the `TextView` color attribute explicitly to white and it won't change in touch events.

Comment: Derp on me. I was referencing `@android:color/primary_text_dark` not realizing it was a selector!